# lodash - how to _.filter the childs and return all parents from a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, lodash

I have created route.js file. Based on queryString it has to filter the Json object. When I used _.filter method it returns entire object as response. Actually i want filter that productlist node and include the remaining nodes as response
Please Help me .. Thanks in Advance...

Here is the code..

**The JSON File**

```
{
    "productList": [
        {
            "productName": "xyz",
            "productType": "mobile"
        },
        {
            "productName": "xyz",
            "productType": "mobile"
        },
        {
            "productName": "xyz",
            "productType": "mobile"
        }
    ],
    "totalProducts": 3,
    "FilteredProducts": 0,
    "test1": 11,
    "test11": 12,
    "test33": 13
}
```

**route.js**

```
var filterByProduct = function(coll, productType){
    return  _.forEach(coll, function(o){
        return _.find(o, function(item){
        });
    });
};
var queryString = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.productType ) {
        var stringObj = JSON.stringify(filterByProduct(jsonFile, req.query.productType),null,4);
        res.end(stringObj);
    } else if (req.query !== {}) {
        var stringObj = JSON.stringify(jsonFile,null,4);
        res.end(stringObj);
    } else {
        res.end('Not a Query String');
    }
}

router.get('/test', queryString, function(req,res){
//
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `filterByProduct` parameter `coll` isn't bound to the `productList` array but the top-level object that contains the `productList` array as well as the other nodes. So you should be targeting `coll.productList` instead.

Also, using `_.filter` (on `coll.productList`) as you originally mentioned is a better idea than using `_.forEach` because it iterates through the array and filters the items. Try this version of `filterByProduct` instead:

```
var filterByProduct = function(coll, productType){
    return _.filter(coll.productList, function(o) {
        return o.productType === productType;
    })
};
```

Finally, to return an object similar to your JSON data file that has the filtered version of `productList` nodes plus the other top-level nodes, you could use the `_.clone` method to shallow clone your `jsonFile` object and then overwrite the `productList` and `FilteredProducts` properties with the values returned from your `filterByProduct` function and the length of the results of `filterByProduct`, respectively. Here's what I came up with:

```
if (req.query.productType) {
    var stringObj = _.clone(jsonFile);
    stringObj.productList = filterByProduct(jsonFile, req.query.productType);
    stringObj.FilteredProducts = stringObj.productList.length;
    res.end(stringObj);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!